# Setting JAVA_OPTS and JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, java-opts

Running a large Gradle build (with JDK7) I receive two `OutOfMemoryErrors`:

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Test worker"
```

When I set the two environment variables below, the build runs through and works just fine:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xms768m"
./gradlew test --stacktrace
...
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xms768m
...
```

Is there a way to include those settings in `gradle.properties` or in `build.gradle`? If yes, what is the correct usage?

I already tried this in `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    System.setProperty('JAVA_OPTS', "-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m")
    System.setProperty('JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS', "-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xms768m")
}
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: Did you find my answer useful anyhow?

Answer (score 5):

Could you please try to create a `gradle.properties` file which should be located next to root `build.gradle` and will it with the following content:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

Another option is to set the required options via `compileJava` task, please see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile:options) and [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.html).

Unfortunately no idea how `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` can be set, it seems unsupported.

Comment: So the solution is `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` is not supported and needs to be set in every CI/CD environment and developer's machine manually?

Comment: @user3105453, probaly yes.

Comment: I believe that `org.gradle.jvmargs` only affects the memory configuration of the Gradle daemon, not the JVM.

Comment: @Gi0rgi0s yes you are correct. its does not affect the forked JVM

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather the gradlew is intended to be tweaked. So adding those environment variables in the gradlew script would be acceptable and the setting would be available in all CI environments.

Answer (score 0):

since this question is old but still relevant, I post what i found in the official docs:

Basically, the run scripts which are generated by `gradlew distZip` have an argument JAVA_OPTS set which can be set via using the gradle plugin 'application' and setting it via

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

...
application {
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ['-Dgreeting.language=en']
}
```

in this example i am setting a system property 'greeting.language' to 'en'.

In similar fashion you can do set JVM args like this:

```
application {
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ['-Xmx2048m', '-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m']
}
```

Found this in the official docs, for [Gradle 6.9.1 and newer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:application_usage)